# Java JDBC connections and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a scenario and the question follows

Application server has two connections pools to DB. `A` and `B`

`A` points to -> `DatabaseA` -> has `128 connections`

`A` has Stored Procedures which access tables residing in `DatabaseB` over the `DB link`

`B` points to -> `DatabaseB` -> has `36 connections`

Now lets say that Java code calls Stored Proc in `DatabaseA` by using connection pool `A`.  This stored proc is getting data over the DB link from `DatabaseB`

**Question:**

Based on this scenario if we get `connection closed` errors on the front end. Is it viable to say that even though java is calling the SP (in `DatabaseA`) from pool A (128) but since the SP is bringing data from `DatabaseB` it has less amount of connections (36).

Basically I want to know when the data is brought over the DB link like this...does it take away from 36 connections assigned to pool B pointint to DatabaseB?

**Exact Exception**
Exact exception I get is: `--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection`

Some Stack trace:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException:
>   Closed Connection     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:185)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForList(GeneralStatement.java:123)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:614)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:588)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:268)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.executeWithListResult(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:219)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:266)

Also, I am using iBatis ...so don't have `try..catch..finally` blocks

Comment: It shouldn't. Please update your question to include the exact exception and the datasource configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The stored procedure is running *in* the database; when it makes the connection to the other database it makes a direct connection and doesn't go through the app server's pool. In fact, it could make a connection to *any* database that is linked to A, regardless whether or not there's a connection pool to that database maintained by the app server.

Answer (score 0):

This exception indicates a resource leak, i.e. the JDBC code is not properly closing connections in the `finally` block (to ensure that it's closed even in case of an exception) or the connection is been shared among multiple threads. If two threads share the same connection from the pool and one thread closes it, then this exception will occur when the other thread uses the connection.

The JDBC code should be written so that connections (and statements and resultsets) are acquired and closed (in reversed order) in the very same method block. E.g.

```
Connection connection = null;
// ...
try {
     connection = database.getConnection();
     // ...
} finally {
     // ...
     if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

Another possible cause is that the pool is holding connections too long idle and not testing/verifying them before releasing. This is configureable in a decent connection pool. Consult its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

"Basically I want to know when the data is brought over the DB link like this...does it take away from 36 connections assigned to pool B pointint to DatabaseB?"

No. The database server will make a distinct connection to the other database server irrespective of any connection pool.

I have to suffer a firewall that cuts of connections after a period of inactivity so I see this error quite a lot. Look into dbms_session.close_database_link, since the database link connection would generally remain for the duration of the session (and since you have a connection pool, that session probably sits around for a very long time).

Comment: I have something like that also. it kills sessions if they run for a long period of time (9 secs) but this killer job only runs in databaseA.  When this happens I actually see "your session has been killed" rather than "closed connection"

Comment: Are you suggesting that at the end of the stored procedure i should have dbms_session.close_database_link? or close the database link after i am dont using the tables that are over DB link?

Comment: I suggest you close the database link at the end of the transaction

Comment: in my stored procedure i am not 'creating' a db link. there are views created which point to tables on the other DB. So never do i specifically open a db link.  However, can i still close the db link at the end to be sure??

Comment: Yes. If your session uses a table/view across a DB link then it opens a session on the remote database. That will persist until your session closes it (or disconnects) or explicitly closed.